# A list of error in my site

Tags: sql, database, vbulletin

I don't know why my site give me this error. This is the list of errors. 
plz lid me ! what shall i do ?

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 6029312) (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 7216


Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 7602176) (tried to allocate 1245184 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/misc.php(89) : eval()'d code on line 1534


Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 786432) (tried to allocate 1245184 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/showthread.php on line 1789



Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 7340032) (tried to allocate 30201 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/includes/class_core.php(4633) : eval()'d code on line 627



Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 77824 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 2550





Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set in [path]/includes/class_core.php on line 417

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [path]/includes/class_core.php:5615) in [path]/includes/functions.php on line 4513
```

Database error

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 786432) (tried to allocate 311296 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/includes/init.php on line 552

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 3145728) (tried to allocate 19456 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/includes/functions.php on line 8989




Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 311296 bytes) in /home/lifegat/domains/life-gate.ir/public_html/forum.php on line 475



Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set in [path]/includes/class_core.php on line 417

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [path]/includes/class_core.php:5615) in [path]/includes/functions.php on line 4513
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase `memory_limit` in `php.ini` or slim your code.

Comment: I can't acces to php.ini . my server is shared .what shall i do ?

Comment: Try setting it via `.htaccess` - do you have access to that? If not, you are out of luck: The server doesn't allow you to use so much memory.

Comment: As I said: You are out of luck. Switch to a better hoster or slim your code.

Comment: so please lid me . how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

`Fatal error: Out of memory` means that the server is out of reserved memory. This usually happens when you are working with big objects, such as images.

The solution is to use the `&` operator. This makes a variable point towards another object. Example:

```
$object = new BigObject();
$copy = $object;              // this copies the object thus more memory is required
$pointer = &$object;          // the & makes the $pointer variable point to $object
```

Because the variable is pointed to another variable, if you change one, the other will change as well.

```
$object = new BigObject();
$pointer = &$object;

$object->x = 12345;

echo $object->x;
echo $pointer->x; // will have the same output as $object->x
```

Pointers are often used in functions, like this:

```
$object = new BigObject();
x( $object );


function x( &$object ) {
     // do stuff with $object
}
```

The `Warning: Cannot modify header information` warning is usually given when you are trying to change the header data after sending output. You probably have a `header();` call after you have echo'd something or have some whitespaces before you use the PHP open tag `<?php`.

Finally, the `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set` error is usually a MySQL issue. But knowing you are out of memory, you might fix the other errors first.

Comment: Thx but where i can change that ?

Comment: I already gave you suggestions for the Out of memory error. For the other error you should just replace the `header();` function somewhere else or just don't echo stuff before the header call